# JavaScript/jQuery mimic browser loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to mimic the effect of a browser loading a page with jQuery. I have an ajax based navigation set up with HTML5 history, but I'm lacking of the feel of the page loading. Facebook seems to have done this. All the calls on the page are done with ajax, yet the browser does a loading effect as if it was loading a regular link.

How would this be done? Have an ajax based navigation system that mimics native browser loading?

Edit:

My question is probably not clear enough, so I'll provide an example:

When browsing a regular page, what happens when you click a regular link the browser (let's use Firefox, because browsers behave differently..):

1. The tab title changes to "Connecting.."
2. The favicon changes to a spinner
3. The lower left popup displays "Loading/reading/waiting [link]" when it loads images, javascript files etc.

So everything above is what I consider native link click behaviour. Is there any way to mimic it (and not by changing the title or favicon temporarily)

Edit2:

This mimicking works somehow on Facebook. Using Firebug and navigating around, you can clearly see that the page doesn't change, yet the browser does the native loading stuff like changing the favicon to spinner, tab title changes to Connecting etc. The URL is rewritten with HTML5 history and the content is retrieved via `/ajax/home/generic.php?ajaxpipe=1...` How do they do that?....

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "a loading effect as if it was loading a regular link?"

Comment: @EdCottrell - I've updated my question with an example